# Disable MSBuild WPP for a specific web project in a solution

Tags: msbuild, msbuild-wpp

I have a Visual Studio solution with a number of projects, two of which are configured as Web Applications.

Project A is used as a class library, but it includes TypeScript files. In order to get the .ts files compiling into .js files, the .csproj file was updated so that it imports Microsoft.WebApplication.targets as well as Microsoft.TypeScript.targets. (The generated .js files are configured as 'Embedded Resources').

Project B is a regular Web Application and references Project A.

Compiling with `msbuild /p:DeployOnBuild=true` causes the Web Publishing Pipeline to be invoked on both projects (packaging up the contents).

Is there a way to prevent (or minimise) WPP running on Project A?